# Switch updating - Cisco Prime

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios

I'm tasked with mass updating of our Cisco switches via Cisco Prime. Is it possible for the update to fail? Can the switch 'hang' in reboot loop? What if I tell Cisco prime to backup running image?

Some of the switches are located in branch offices - can't quickly get there to deal with bad update/switch hanging in reboot loop.

Comment: We've had lots of problems regarding software upgrades via Prime. The most annoying error Primes makes, is not setting the bootvar correctly on new (3650, 3850, 9300 for instance) switches. This results in equipment, that does not work correctly when rebooted. My personal suggestion would be to check everything before you reload. We're using Prime version 3.4.

Comment: I'll have to update about 30 Cisco 2960S(or G), do you happen to know if these are also affected? 
So your suggestion is to not force reboot after completion, but to simply deploy it, then check it and then reboot if all ok?

Comment: We haven't had problems with the 2960S/X series luckily. We have about 2000 of these and they've not produced any problems when using Prime to upgrade them. If you have 30 you could deploy and then check before reboot in order to be sure, that everything is done correctly. I'm confident with the 2960S/X Series. :-)

Comment: Thank you, you have made me worry about this thing a bit less :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer.

We've had problems regarding software upgrades via Prime on new equipment, like the 3650, 3850, 9000 Series from Cisco. Prime is not setting the bootvar correctly and often, this results in the switch not being able to boot or not being upgraded i.e. rebooting on the old software. We've created a TAC case with Cisco, but it's low priority.

We haven't had problems with the 2960S/X series luckily. We have about 2000 of these and they've not produced any problems when using Prime to upgrade them. Last time 1% didn't work, but that was hardware related. The only flaw to note is when Prime tries to upgrade this type of switch and the flash is full. This will generate an error while deploying fortunately.

I'm pretty confident, that you can upgrade your 2960S/X series without any problems.

Comment: One more thing - I have one Cisco SG300-28 which I'll have to upgrade too. Any experience with that type? I was unable to properly connect that thing to Cisco Prime. Collection Failure, even when both SSH and SNMP access is correctly set.

Comment: @Jlisk unfortunately that is not supported.

Comment: I thought I saw it supported in the documentation of Cisco Prime (Cisco Prime Infrastructure 3.3 Supported Devices PI33-Supported-Device-List.xlsx)?

Thanks for telling me, though.

Comment: @Jlisk Ok, but we're on 3.4 and there it's not supported, definitely not for software upgrades. I can just see it in the list, but i cannot do anything to it.

Comment: Thank you for all the info, that's all from me :)